# Override WooCommerce page-specific js in my theme

Tags: plugins

How can I replace the WooCommerce page-specific .js files with my own versions? For example on the cart page there's /plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/cart.min.js but I'd like to load
/themes/mythem/woocommerce/js/cart.min.js in its place.

Answer (score 2):

It's common to find theme that you can't simply override certain file by mirroring the file structure in your child theme.

In this case the cart.min.js is most likely included via [wp_queue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) so you gotta find the handle of the script by looking at the source code of WooCommerce (just search by wp_enqueue_script). Then you can run [wp_dequeue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) on that handle.

Lastly, you run wp_enqueue_script on your own js file to include it in your template.

Comment: Yes, the rub with WC is that there's a bunch of logic to conditionally enqueue the scripts based on the page context. So I'm not sure how maintainable this will be.

Answer (score 1):

First You should remove a registered script, register a new script then enqueue a script.

Check the following scripts to replace checkout.min.js with custom checkout script.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shopkeeper_wp_enqueue_scripts_for_frontend', 99 );
function shopkeeper_wp_enqueue_scripts_for_frontend(){
    if( is_checkout() ){
        // Checkout Page        
        wp_deregister_script('wc-checkout');
        wp_register_script('wc-checkout', SHOPKEEPER_JS_PATH . "override_checkout.js", 
        array( 'jquery', 'woocommerce', 'wc-country-select', 'wc-address-i18n' ), WC_VERSION, TRUE);
        wp_enqueue_script('wc-checkout');
    }
}
```